# How to access iDRAC from outside network. or through DDNS

Tags: dell-poweredge

How to access iDRAC from outside network or through DDNS.

Iam using iDRAC over LAN, but how to use from outside network even from outside country.

I already own Dyndns and using HG8245Q Router.

Any chance?

Comment: Create a VPN into your internal management network (or use SSH port forwarding).  Don't try to make it accessible with just port forwarding due to security concerns.

Comment: how to configure SSH port forwarding in IDRAC settings and HG8245Q Router.

Comment: Is IPv6 an option? If yes, then just use the IPv6 address as displayed by the idrac

Answer (score 2):

#iwork4dell.  The iDRAC users guide contains all the port information for remote access.  I do agree with the comments that a VPN would be better for security.  There are several home routers that support openVPN that are fairly inexpensive.  Another options is to enable OS to iDRAC pass-through then install openVPN on the server.

see http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/19/poweredge-r630/idrac8_2.30.30.30_ug/idrac-port-information?guid=guid-84daf55c-3171-49fc-b423-cc870f508689&lang=en-us

http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/dell-idrac-service-module-2.0/idrac8_ug_pub-v1/enabling-or-disabling-os-to-idrac-pass-through?guid=guid-e44413c7-969c-4c76-91f2-f6d9076a57b7&lang=en-us

Answer (score 0):

I am using the GL-MT300N-V2 travel router (aka Mango) after a few configurations changes.  This does require running a VPN server somewhere on the internet for the Mango to connect into.  Here's what works for me:

1. Connect to the Mango via its LAN port
2. Install base OpenWRT firmware and login to luci
3. Disable WiFi (delete the LAN AP under wireless)
4. Disable IPv6 (optional; delete WAN6 iface under interfaces)
5. Disable forwarding (change LAN->WAN forward from allow to reject)
6. Set a static IP on the WAN port if no dhcp is present
7. Connect WAN port to internal network and verify internet access
8. Install WireGuard or openVPN opkg and create vpn interface in LAN zone
9. Install Squid3 opkg (HTTP proxy) and configure src/dst nets to allow
10. Connect LAN port on Mango to iDRAC port on Dell

I'm then able to browse to luci on the Mango at the VPN IP, view the DHCP leases to find the address assigned to the iDRAC, and connect to the iDRAC via the squid proxy running on the Mango.  I use SwitchyOmega to specify the proxy, but a PAC file would also work.

Note: don't skimp on the power adapter quality; get a name brand that is verified to be UL-listed.  You don't want to burn down a data center because you used a cheap knockoff.  Even so, expect feedback from your data center manager since this is clearly not enterprise-grade gear.  But still, it's hard to beat for $35USD!

#dontworkfordell but think an outbound UDP-based VPN should be a native option on the iDRACs...